Are there any ways to solve the Frobenius-Perron equation for invariant probability density of discrete chaotic maps?
I'm looking at the discrete map $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x) =\ln{|x|},\quad  f(x_{n+1})=f(x_n)$$
where the initial $x_0$ is not of the form $\pm e^{\pm e^{\pm e^{\dots}}}$ a finite number of times, and $x_0$ doesn't lie on any periodic trajectories.
I expect the map to be chaotic, but also most iterates $x_n$ to be $\mathcal{O}(1)$ because $\ln{x}$ reduces large numbers very quickly. However, I do not know how to prove this.
I want to find the limiting distribution of iterates as $n\to \infty$, if it exists. In other words, I want to find the invariant probability density $\rho(x)$ that is an eigenfunction of the Frobenius-Perron operator with eigenvalue 1:
\begin{align*}
\rho(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy\, \rho(y) \, \delta\big(x-f(y)\big)\\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{0}dy \, \rho(y) \, \delta\big(x-\ln{(-y)}\big) + \int_{0}^{\infty}dy \, \rho(y) \, \delta\big(x-\ln{(y)}\big)\\
\implies \rho(x) &= e^{x}\big(\rho(-e^{x})+\rho(e^{x})\big)
\end{align*}
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac-delta function that satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx f(x)\delta(x-x_0) = f(x_0)$.
Additionally, $\rho(x)\geq 0$.
I want to find a normalisable solution to this functional equation, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\,\rho(x)<\infty$. Is there a way to prove that such a solution exists, and/or solve the equation?
I iterated the function and plotted a normalised histogram for $10^5$ iterates on Python. Here's what the distribution looks like:
Image here

This looks like a Gumbel law. Maybe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution
